# Error running MySQL Server

Tags: mysql

Have following error:

```
skydos@skydos-laptop:/$ service mysql start
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; 
        type="method_call", 
        sender=":1.41"     (uid=1000 pid=1827 comm="start mysql ")
        interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" 
        member="Start" error name="(unset)" 
        requested_reply=0 
        destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1     comm="/sbin/init"))
skydos@skydos-laptop:/$
```

How to solve this problem?

More info:

```
 skydos@skydos-laptop:/$ sudo service mysql start
   start: Job is already running: mysql
   skydos@skydos-laptop:/$ pidof mysql
   skydos@skydos-laptop:/$ pidof mysqld
   skydos@skydos-laptop:/$ htop
   skydos@skydos-laptop:/$ sudo service mysql start
   start: Job is already running: mysql
```

Comment: There are bunch of possible answers here : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1469902 - however I think this not a programming question, rather an installation or system issue as the message is from the OS.

Comment: "Job is already running: mysql" << seems obvious enough to me?

Comment: "ps aux | grep -i mysql" check what's going on there.

Comment: nothing.
problem solved - new installation of MySQL

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try running the service command as root (e.g sudo).